# Missing Horizontal Line in MPAndroidchart bottom

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I've created an android apps using library from the wonderful **MPAndroidchart**, unfortunately I have run into a little bit of bugs. When the phone set the font into a bigger size the bottom line in the graphic seems to disappear, but if the device is using normal font size the line in the bottom still visible

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/app_col_transparent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/FragmentTrenMonth_lnFilter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3">



        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_20sdp"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/app_background_white">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
                android:id="@+id/FragmentTrenMonth_spnMaterial"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_20sdp"></android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:layout_weight="0.9"
            android:background="@color/app_background_white">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
                android:id="@+id/FragmentTrenMonth_spnSatuan"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_20sdp"
                android:entries="@array/spiner_arrays_tren"></android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/app_background_white"
            android:visibility="invisible">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
                android:id="@+id/FragmentTrenMonth_spnFormId"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_20sdp"></android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
        android:id="@+id/FragmentTrenMonth_chart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_250sdp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/FragmentTrenMonth_lnFilter"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you show the xml file

Comment: I have provide the screenshot and XML for the layout

Answer (score 0):

Use below line in your code:

```
chart.getXAxis().setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);  // for showing below axis

chart.getXAxis().setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.TOP); // for top 

chart.getXAxis().setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTH_SIDED); // for showing top and bottom both
```